# Connection decorator - how to pass values?

Tags: python, decorator, python-decorators

First, I am working on decorator like this. Basically it's ssh tunnel from host to radio module trough serv.
host <-- serv(ssh) --> radio_module(telnet)

```
def connect(serv_ip, serv_port,
            serv_ssh_username,
            serv_ssh_password,
            radio_module_ip,
            radio_module_port=2323,
            host_ip='127.0.0.1',
            host_port=10022):
    def decorator(f):
        def wrapper():
            with SSHTunnelForwarder(
                    (serv_ip, int(serv_port)),
                    ssh_username=serv_ssh_username,
                    ssh_password=serv_ssh_password,
                    remote_bind_address=(radio_module_ip, int(radio_module_port)),
                    local_bind_address=(host_ip, int(host_port)),
                    # for debugging purposes:
                    # logger=create_logger(loglevel=1),
            ):
                with TelnetClient(host_ip, int(host_port)) as telnet:
                    f(telnet)
        return wrapper
    return decorator
```

Now, I wish to set up such connection, do some operations and close. As I want to use such schema for multiple methods, I thought, that decorator should do the job, so I've prepared smth like...

```
from server import Server

class SystemModule(object):
    def __init__(self, server, username, password, hostname):
        self.server = server
        self.hostname = hostname
        self.username = username
        self.password = password

   @connect(
       serv_ip=???,
       serv_port=???,
       serv_ssh_username=???,
       serv_ssh_password=???,
       radio_module_ip=???,
   )
   def do_some_stuff(self, connection):
       #doing stuff
```

However I cannot give there parameters with 'self' as decorator is created before method is initialized, right (it's my first decorator, I might say smth. wrong), like:

<s>serv_ip=self.serv.ip,</s>

So how to make this proper? I wish to have methods wrapped in connection without need to copy code every time. Thank you in advance for help

Comment: You won't get the instance `self` until the nested function `wrapper` is called - it will also get the `connection` at that point. If it's going to be so tied to the instance, I'm not sure a decorator is the right thing for you here.

Comment: I am open for proposals. Can you offer better one, please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest to use a context manager instead:

```
from contextlib import contextmanager  
from server import Server

class SystemModule(object):
    def __init__(self, server, serv_ip, serv_port, username, password, hostname,
                 radio_module_ip, radio_module_port=2323, host_ip='127.0.0.1', host_port=10022):
        self.server = server
        self.hostname = hostname
        self.username = username
        self.password = password
        self.serv_ip = serv_ip
        self.serv_port = serv_port
        self.radio_module_ip = radio_module_ip
        self.radio_module_port = radio_module_port
        self.host_ip = host_ip
        self.host_port = host_port

   @contextmanager
   def connect():
        with SSHTunnelForwarder(
                (self.serv_ip, int(self.serv_port)),
                ssh_username=self.username,
                ssh_password=self.password,
                remote_bind_address=(self.radio_module_ip, int(self.radio_module_port)),
                local_bind_address=(self.host_ip, int(self.host_port)),
                # for debugging purposes:
                # logger=create_logger(loglevel=1),
        ):
            with TelnetClient(self.host_ip, int(self.host_port)) as telnet:
                yield telnet

   def do_some_stuff(self):
       with self.connect() as connection:
           #doing stuff with connection
           pass
```

Comment: U, I like that. I like that a lot! :D

Comment: @User007 Thanks. You can "accept" the answer if it's what you need.

Comment: Just done. I was testing your solution... works as great as expected. Thank you very much for help!

Comment: @User007 I'm glad to help. Sorry, I thought you don't know how to accept a question, because your profile seems to be new.